# php how to force redirect in case of typo with many slashes

Tags: php, redirect

I have issue, this is correct address : http://localhost/mkv4/index.php

But when someone made typo like below
http://localhost/mkv4/indexdsadsadsadsa.php

Page will be redirected to:
http://localhost/mkv4/index.php

And this is okay, i set up earlier in .htaccess and it works, and its fine.

But when someone make something like this:
http://localhost/mkv4/index.php/dasdsadasdsadsa/dsadsaddsaads/
Then i received index.php, but without css, and url is still with typo, how i can force redirect to index.php, and change url in address bar, no matter how many slashes is in typo?
Sorry but i will gonna crazy soon. Thanks in advance for any help
Regards

EDIT

I have same basic handmade js/php/mysql site without any frameworks/library
I have below .htaccess code

```
ErrorDocument 404 /index.php 
ErrorDocument 500 /index.php 

RewriteEngine On  
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d  
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^projekt/([0-9a-zA-Z_-]+) projekt.php?projekt_url=$1 [NC,L]  

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR] 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR] 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d 
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L] 
RewriteRule ^.*$ 404.php [NC,L]  

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [R=301,L] 
 
FallbackResource /index.php
```

And now i would to redirect to /index.php in case any typo and in case every 404 error, i would like to change url to /index.php everytime after redirect.

But i noticed three scenarios:

1. In case  [localhost/mkv4/indsadsadasads](http://localhost/mkv4/indsadsadasads)
   everything redirect fine to [localhost/mkv4/index.php](http://localhost/mkv4/index.php) and url has been changed so it works perfectly in that case.
2. In case [localhost/mkv4/ingggfdfgdsfgd/dsadsaadsdsa/index.php](http://localhost/mkv4/ingggfdfgdsfgd/dsadsaadsdsa/index.php)
   I got  get infinite redirect loop error :( Could you help me how can i fix that?
3. In case [localhost/mkv4/index.php/projekt/projekt/projekt/session-m-m](http://localhost/mkv4/index.php/projekt/projekt/projekt/session-m-m)
   I got index.php but without css, and url is still broken :( Could you assist again ? :)

Thanks in advance

Comment: Rather than adding details in an answer (which got deleted), please [edit] your question to add the updates.

Answer (score 1):

Simply use a RewriteRule to remove the trailing slash(es) from url

Use the following .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Hi. Thank you for advice, i pasted upper code in .htaccess
And in case http://localhost/mkv4/indsadsadasads everything redirect fine to http://localhost/mkv4/index.php and url has been changed so it is okay 

But i stil in case http://localhost/mkv4/ingggfdfgdsfgd/dsadsaadsdsa/index.php
get infinite redirect loop error
And in case http://localhost/mkv4/index.php/projekt/projekt/projekt/session-m-m 
I got index.php but without css, and url is still broken :(

Comment: My current .htaccess code 


`ErrorDocument 404 /index.php
ErrorDocument 500 /index.php
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f

RewriteRule ^projekt/([0-9a-zA-Z_-]+) projekt.php?projekt_url=$1 [NC,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^.*$ 404.php [NC,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [R=301,L]

FallbackResource /index.php`